# Mdx parameters- pull in all data

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2012, query-string, ssas-tabular

I have a situation where I have a parameter in ssrs that contains only a single value. When that value gets passed over in the mdx query it allows the results to be filters. The values are directly linked to a dimension in the tabular model. However the tabular model only contains ( null, black, blue, red). I can easily get results when the parameter is black, blue or red but I need the results for "Colors" which is a top of the house values that requires us to display the results for all three colors. Any ideas?

Code

```
Select
Non Empty
{ ( Measures.TotalColors]} on columns
,Non Empty
{
[DifferentColors].[Color2].[Color2].allmembers
}
Dimension Properties
Member_Caption
,Member_Unique_name
on Rows
From [Colors]
```

Result

```
Color2   TotalColors
null    100
black   10
blue    23
red     11
```

When the parameter is black then it needs to show 10 and when its blue then it needs to show 23. This is easy using parameters.

However I need the following result when I select "Colors" which should bring in all the values in the dimension.

```
Intended Result

Color2    TotalColors
Colors   144
```

Comment: We cannot help you unless you provide query, you data and expected result in more detailed way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply aggregate data on higher level for all member, however this will not give you Colors

```
Select 
  Non Empty{ ( Measures.TotalColors]} on columns,
  Non Empty{[DifferentColors].[Color2].[All]} on Rows
From [Colors]
```

Or if you want to show Total additionally to list of colors you have to introduce calculated dimension member:

```
WITH MEMBER [DifferentColors].[Color2].[Color2].[Colors] AS 
  SUM([DifferentColors].[Color2].[Color2].MEMBERS, Measures.TotalColors)
Select 
  Non Empty{ ( Measures.TotalColors]} on columns,
  Non Empty{[DifferentColors].[Color2].[Color2].allmembers} on Rows
From [Colors]
```